# Implementing a complex data structure in ExtJS forms

Tags: forms, extjs, data-structures, extjs4

We have a client with a requirement of rather complex data-model. Meaning the data-model is not only quite huge (around 500-1000 fields, nested in many objects) it is also required to send and received all data at any time which is all time a field get changed (after it looses focus). We get it all as JSON. Here is a structure example:

```
{
    data: {
        somefield: 'some content'
    },
    label: {
        somelabel: 'some label text'
    },
    applyable: {
        somefield: {
            visible: false
        }
    }
    someSubForm: {
        data: {
            somefield: 'some content'
        },
        label: {
            somelabel: 'some label text'
        },
        anotherSubForm: {
            data: {
                somefield: 'some content'
            },
            label: {
                somelabel: 'some label text'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But that is not all; the model also contains labels, tooltips and other configurations. All data need to be displayed in multiple tabs where it is possible that the same data is displayed in two different tabs. Due to the required layout (defined by the client) the forms will be nested into each other.

The backend is provided by our customer so I can't change anything here.

I began by using a single model with a defined proxy to load the JSON. But after that I ran into several problems.

First is that the form will always track all fields, even the one of nested forms
Second is that I cannot change any labels or apply custom settings
Third is that due to the huge amount of data the loadRecord() and getValues() methods runs quite long.

My question is how can I break this down so that each form only processes it's own data and not all data and how would I be able to apply custom settings?

Comment: Does the backend allow to read/save individual simple fields that constitute the huge model? Or does it require the frontend to pass the whole data structure when only a single field has been updated?

Comment: I need to pass all changeable fields back, which make 75% of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution that I use for now:

First some facts:

1. I will have to cover multiple R/W operations (in particular after every field that changed and looses focus)
2. I always get all data back on each request
3. I have to cover a huge amount of data (field data, store data, labels and configurations)
4. I have to optimize this mess to be performance critical
5. There is no way to store anything in a server side session
6. The forms are nested wildly one into another and may also be split up or exists twice

Here's what I do for now:

I drop all associations and decided to go with just one Model extended from a Model with a modified `getData` method which supports a custom root property like `someSubForm` (see my example code in the question). The fields are configured as auto so so changes to the reader or writer are needed.
Maybe not rock solid but it works.

Next big problem are the forms. The form will always try to set each field even if it is in another form. In addition I need to set quite a lot standalone labels. So the default form cannot be used, should I extend? But how and where should I start? After a long look at the source it seems to me that I cannot extend so I decided to create a totally custom form class along with a custom mixin class and custom form.basic class. 
Why? Because I need to form to look only at the field directly placed into this form, be able to set labels and hand the model instance to any nested form.

With that I can now register my own monitor instances with a custom selector each. Oh,I forgot the first thing about my new form; it is bound to a entity by a property which contains the name (like `someSubForm`).

This is used when

1. A Item is added to the form

   - any field get a formId
   - any label get a formId (not the labels that are bound to a form)
   - any form get a parentFormId and the instance
2. The Monitor selectors are setted
3. A model is load into a form
4. Data is fetched from a model

Second is that there are now 3 monitor instances

1. Collect all fields by using the new selector which also looks for the Entity. By that any subform fields get ignored, cause they have their own entity
2. All the same for labels
3. Collect all forms

The third is the modified `loadRecord` method which uses the new `getData()` method of the model and sets the specific data to fields, labels and the whole model to any form.

All in all I have a performance boost of 800% with that.

Answer (score 2):

Since you cannot split your JSON, you need a monolitic model for webservice i/o: This is what you already have.

But when the user is working with the data, you should focus on the required data, to reduce time spend for loading and updating. So I would suggest to define additional models and stores, that back each of your tabs, or each form in your tabs. Given your data sample, you could e.g. create a form model, which is created after your big i/o model got loaded (either in the callback or you listen to the load event) by copying data. You could even defer this costly copy operation to the moment when the user opens the respective tab.

I see there is a sub form, so maybe you can try to add an association to the form model itself.

```
Ext.define('YourApp.model.FormModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    { name: 'data'},
    { name: 'label'}
],
associations: [ {
        type: 'hasMany',
        model: 'YourApp.model.FormModel',
        associationKey: 'someSubForm' 
    }
]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it did not worked out for me. I posted my solution.

Comment: Quite complicated, but I think I got the idea.